# Quartz Spring: Scheduler doesn't fire up on server restart

Tags: java, spring, quartz-scheduler

I have implemented Spring Quartz in my application with the following settings:

```
JobDataMap jobDataMap = new JobDataMap();
jobDataMap.put("data", data);
JobKey jobKey = new JobKey(startJob, groupName);
JobDetail  jobDetail = JobBuilder.newJob(StartJob.class).withIdentity(jobKey).setJobData(jobDataMap).storeDurably().build();
TriggerKey triggerKey = new TriggerKey("INTEGRATION_START_TRIGGER_" + data, groupName);
Trigger trigger = TriggerBuilder.newTrigger().withIdentity(triggerKey).forJob(jobKey).withSchedule(CronScheduleBuilder.dailyAtHourAndMinute(date.getHourOfDay(), date.getMinuteOfHour()).withMisfireHandlingInstructionDoNothing()).build();

schedulerFactoryBean.setSchedulerName("INTEGRATION_SCHEDULER");

// Start Job
schedulerFactoryBean.setJobDetails(jobDetail);
schedulerFactoryBean.setTriggers(trigger);
schedulerFactoryBean.afterPropertiesSet();
schedulerFactoryBean.start();
```

This job is configured as persistent with MySQL DB. I can view the TRIGGERS and JOB details in the DB table. It works (fires everytime) until the server is shutdown. After restart, the scheduler doesn't fire up not even once.

**quartz.properties**

```
# Main Quartz configuration
org.quartz.scheduler.instanceName=DatabaseScheduler
org.quartz.scheduler.instanceId=AUTO
org.quartz.scheduler.rmi.export = false
org.quartz.scheduler.rmi.proxy = false
org.quartz.scheduler.jobFactory.class=org.quartz.simpl.SimpleJobFactory
org.quartz.jobStore.class=org.quartz.impl.jdbcjobstore.JobStoreTX
org.quartz.jobStore.driverDelegateClass=org.quartz.impl.jdbcjobstore.StdJDBCDelegate
org.quartz.jobStore.dataSource=quartzDataSource
org.quartz.jobStore.tablePrefix=QRTZ_
org.quartz.jobStore.isClustered=false
org.quartz.threadPool.class=org.quartz.simpl.SimpleThreadPool
org.quartz.threadPool.threadCount=5

# JobStore: JDBC jobStoreTX
org.quartz.dataSource.quartzDataSource.driver=com.mysql.jdbc.Driver
org.quartz.dataSource.quartzDataSource.URL=jdbc:mysql://localhost:3306/scheduler
org.quartz.dataSource.quartzDataSource.user=root
org.quartz.dataSource.quartzDataSource.password=root
```

Is there any additional configuration that I am missing?